# Webpack configuration: source-maps and development/production mode

Tags: webpack, source-maps

So, I have the following configuration for Webpack. I have only 2 doubts:

1. how can I switch from Development mode to Production mode by simply changing my command?
   At the moment I use the command "npm run dev", and as in the file webpack.config.js is configured only 1 fixed mode (development) it automatically compiles for development. I would like to use something like "npm run prod".
2. I am doubting that the Source-maps is working correctly. If I inspect for example the H1 tag in the browser, it tells me that the styles of this tag come from the file bcef8.css:226. However this file doesn't really exist, and actually comes from src/styles/generals/_typo.scss:21
   [image]

[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
// Configuración de Webpack

const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    // Modo de desarrollo o producción
    mode: 'development',
    // Activar el modo de vigilancia
    watch: true,
    // Archivos de entrada
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    // Mapas de origen
    devtool: 'source-map',
    // Archivos de salida
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    // Cargadores
    module: {
        // Regla para archivos CSS
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(c|sc|sa)ss$/,
                use: [
                    // Extrae el código CSS de los archivos JavaScript
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    // Cargador CSS estándar
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 2
                        },
                    },
                    // Cargador PostCSS
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    [
                                        "autoprefixer",
                                        {
                                            overrideBrowserslist: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%']
                                        },
                                    ],
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    // Cargador SASS
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    // Optimizaciones
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            // Minificador de JavaScript
            new TerserPlugin(),
            // Minificador de CSS
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ],
        minimize: true,
    },
    // Plugins
    plugins: [
        // Extrae el código CSS de los archivos JavaScript
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.min.css'
        }),
        // Inicia un servidor de desarrollo
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: 'http://localhost/portfolio',
            files: ['dist'],
            injectCss: true,
        },
            { reload: true, })
    ]
};
```

and the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<h1>Portfolio.</h1> <p>www.portfolio.com</p>",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"    
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```